# Installing Ubuntu On a Separate HDD

Tags: grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I was wondering if I could install ubuntu on a 500GB HDD while there are already 2 other HDDs in RAID 0 with windows 8 installed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and decrease the length of sentences as it is difficult to understand the question in it's current state.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy this is a fun one, I went through this more times than I Care to admit :)

Disclaimer: I don't have RAID on the Windows Drives, so not sure if it will have any effect

1. Install Windows (you already have it so skip)
2. Boot to Ubuntu USB/CD and go to install
3. When you get to the screen that asks you to automatically or manually partition, select manual
4. Find your drive and create a new partition table
5. Create Root mount point for the size of the drive minus swap
6. Create Swap pasrtition
7. VERY IMPORTANT (this is where RAID may screw up, so make sure you have a backup) for the bootloader location choose you Windows Drive, this will install GRUB to replace Windows Bootloader. Every other way I've tried didn't work
8. (Optional) I'd recommend also installing rEFInd, it's extremely helpful for managing multi boot environments